# Final Ratio will not calculate. Is my class method called wrong?

Tags: class, variables, object, methods

In my code I ahve to calculate the number of delayed flights/total flights for airliners. I have written the code and everything works except the final ratio printout. does anyone see the problem?

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
// javac -classpath .;opencsv-2.3.jar flightinfo.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class flightinfo2{

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("delayed.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;

    Map<String, Carrier> airlines = new HashMap<String, Carrier>();         

    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // At this point, nextLine is the name of the carrier, e.g., "Continental"
            // nextLine can be used as the key in your "airlines" map. E.g., airlines.put(nextLine, new Carrier());

        if (airlines.containsKey(nextLine[1])){
        airlines.get(nextLine[1]).addNumFlights(Integer.valueOf(nextLine[6]));
        airlines.get(nextLine[1]).addNumDelayed(Integer.valueOf(nextLine[7]));
        airlines.get(nextLine[1]).setDelayedRatio();
        }
        else {
          airlines.put(nextLine[1], new Carrier());
          airlines.get(nextLine[1]).setName(nextLine[1]);
          airlines.get(nextLine[1]).setNumFlights(Integer.valueOf(nextLine[6]));
          airlines.get(nextLine[1]).setNumDelayed(Integer.valueOf(nextLine[7]));
        }
    }
airlines.get("Continental").print();
airlines.get("Atlantic Southeast").print();
airlines.get("American Eagle").print();
airlines.get("Delta").print();
airlines.get("ExpressJet").print();
airlines.get("United").print();
airlines.get("SkyWest").print();
airlines.get("US Airways").print();
airlines.get("JetBlue").print();
airlines.get("American").print();
airlines.get("Mesa").print();
airlines.get("Frontier").print();
airlines.get("AirTran").print();
airlines.get("Southwest").print();  

}
}
```

the Class

```
public class Carrier{
String name;
int totalFlights;
int delayedFlights;
int totalDelayedRatio;

public Carrier(){}

public void setName(String s){
name = s;
}
public void setNumDelayed(int n){
delayedFlights = n;
}

public void setNumFlights(int s){
totalFlights = s;
}

public void addNumDelayed(int n){
delayedFlights = delayedFlights + n;
}

public void addNumFlights(int s){
totalFlights = delayedFlights + s;
}

public void setDelayedRatio(){
totalDelayedRatio = (delayedFlights/totalFlights);
}

public void print(){
System.out.printf("%s:\t%d,\t%d,\t%d\n", name, totalFlights, delayedFlights, totalDelayedRatio);
}
```

}

the printout looks like this:
    Continental:    92,     81,     0 <---should be the ratio
    ...more carriers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
totalDelayedRatio = (delayedFlights/totalFlights);
```

Try using "this" explicitly:

```
this.totalDelatedRatio = (delayedFlights/totalFlights);
```

Comment: I edited the method to what I originally had by the way- as a void. But, this.totalDelayedRatio did not up date the variable